# Syntax error: word unexpected ( expecting "fi" )

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, scripting, sh

i try do the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat test.txt
echo "Write del if you want delete or write save if you want save"
read s1
echo "Which symbol"
read s2
if [ $s1 = "del" ]
then
sed -i "/^$s2/d"
cat test.txt
if [ $s1 = "save" ]
then
echo "saved"
else
echo "Error"
fi cat test.txt
```

and i have error in - Syntax error: word unexpected ( expecting "fi" )
Help please!

Comment: Paste your script at https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check syntax errors.

Comment: You've got two `if` but only one `fi`, `bash` expects one `fi` for each `if` you open ; since both your conditions are exclusive (one can't be true if the other is), consider using `elif` instead of your second `if`, which would also solve the problem.

Comment: In the statement `if [ $s1 = "del" ]`, you've got the quotes exactly wrong.  Stylistically, you should probably quote both arguments (`if [ "$1" = "del" ]` (although I've never understood why the stylistic argument for quotes doesn't have you write `if "[" "$1" "=" "del" "]";`), but if you're going to be sparse with quotes, they are not necessary around `del` but are required around `$1`.  IOW, you should change it to `if [ "$1" = del ]`

Comment: I vote to close this question as it is based on a simple syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

Indenting code inside of an `if` block or loops can help catch issues like this. Every `if` needs a `fi` to end the block. Indenting your code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat test.txt
echo "Write del if you want delete or write save if you want save"
read s1
echo "Which symbol"
read s2

if [ $s1 = "del" ]
then
    sed -i "/^$s2/d"
    cat test.txt

    if [ $s1 = "save" ]
    then
        echo "saved"
    else
        echo "Error"
    fi cat test.txt
```

You can see that the initial block is not closed with it's own `fi`. Also you have an oddball `cat` hanging out on the same line as your `fi`. That's not supposed to be there. Instead something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat test.txt
echo "Write del if you want delete or write save if you want save"
read s1
echo "Which symbol"
read s2

if [ $s1 = "del" ]
then
    sed -i "/^$s2/d"
    cat test.txt

    if [ $s1 = "save" ]
    then
        echo "saved"
    else
        echo "Error"
    fi 
    cat test.txt
fi
```

There's no guarantee that is going to do what you want, but it's syntactically correct.

I would ***HIGHLY*** suggest dumping this into shellcheck.net so it can point you in the right direction. Specifically the lack of double quotes in your tests that could cause some oddball behavior.

---

Based on @Aaron's comment you are probably looking for something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat test.txt
echo "Write del if you want delete or write save if you want save"
read s1
echo "Which symbol"
read s2

if [ "$s1" = "del" ]; then
    sed -i "/^$s2/d" test.txt    
elif [ "$s1" = "save" ]; then
    echo "saved"
else
    echo "Error"
fi 

cat test.txt
```

Comment: `$s1` can't be both `del` and `save`, I'm guessing OP wanted to use an `elif` there.

Comment: @Aaron Totally agree. I added an edited version of the script at the bottom that *I think* might be what OP is after.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues.

First, you must replace following lines:

```
sed -i "/^$s2/d"
cat test.txt
```

by

```
sed -i "/^$s2/d" test.txt
```

I guess you didn't want to have 2 if/then instructions, but an elsif one, so you should fix your script like this:

```
then
sed -i "/^$s2/d" test.txt
elif [ $s1 = "save" ]
then
echo "saved"
```

In addition, as improvements, I would recommend:

- to put the name of the file in a dedicated variable, for better legibility and maintenability
- to **touch** the file at the beginning of the script, to ensure it exists (even if empty)

Eventually, the script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

filePath="test.txt"

[ ! -f "$filePath" ] && echo -e "ERROR: file $filePath not found. It is required for this script to work properly" >&2 && exit 1

cat "$filePath"
echo "Write del if you want delete or write save if you want save"
read s1
echo "Which symbol"
read s2

if [ "$s1" = "del" ]; then
  sed -i "/^$s2/d" "$filePath"
elif [ "$s1" = "save" ]; then
  echo "saved"
else
  echo "Error"
fi

cat "$filePath"
```

You can see that s1 is quoted in the 'if' to avoid issue if there are space characters.

Comment: Great answer overall, but I'm not too sure about the `touch` suggestion : in many case I'd rather have the script fail with an error (`sed` complaining it can't find the file) than act as if everything is alright while it certainly didn't do what I expected it to. Maybe using `set -e` to avoid running farther than the first error would help avoiding a batch of ugly errors the user might not bother understanding

Comment: I agree, if the file is required for the script, you should replace the touch solution, by this one:

    [ ! -f "$filePath" ] && echo -e "ERROR: file $filePath not found. It is required for this script to work properly" >&2 && exit 1

I edited my initial answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah a guard condition with a not too frightening error is even better :)